# Question regarding Chapter 8 of baby rudin

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, gamma-function

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. For $\alpha > 0$, define $$I_\alpha[f](x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^x (x-t)^{\alpha-1} f(t)dt$$.
Show that the derivate of $I_{\alpha+1}[f]$ is $I_\alpha[f]$ and $I_\alpha[I_\beta[f]]$ = $I_{\alpha+\beta}[f]$ for all $\alpha, \beta > 0$.

I just have no idea where to start on this problem.

Comment: Prove the second claim first (write the LHS as a repeated integral, switch the integrations and apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)), and deduce the first one from it (by noting what $I_1$ is).

Comment: by "this" are you referring to the incomplete beta function? I don't think incomplete beta/gamma functions are mentioned in babyrudin, so would there be another way?

Comment: Why "incomplete"? You must get the complete one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
I_\alpha[I_\beta[f]](x)&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^x(x-y)^{\alpha-1}I_\beta[f](y)\,dy\\&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^x\color{blue}{\int_0^y}(x-y)^{\alpha-1}\color{blue}{(y-z)^{\beta-1}f(z)\,dz}\,dy\\\color{gray}{[\text{switch the integrations}]}&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^x\color{blue}{\int_z^x(x-y)^{\alpha-1}(y-z)^{\beta-1}}f(z)\,\color{blue}{dy}\,dz\\\color{gray}{[\text{substitute }y=z+(x-z)t]}&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^x\color{blue}{\int_0^1}(x-z)^{\alpha+\beta-1}\color{blue}{(1-t)^{\alpha-1}t^{\beta-1}}f(z)\,\color{blue}{dt}\,dz\\\color{gray}{[\text{apply the beta integral}]}&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}\int_0^x(x-z)^{\alpha+\beta-1}f(z)\,dz=I_{\alpha+\beta}[f](x).
\end{align}

Comment: to prove the derivative part, would it be fine to integrate $I_\alpha$ from 0 to x?

Comment: Look back. $I_{\alpha+1}[f]=I_1[I_\alpha[f]]$. What does $I_1$ do?

Comment: I can't believe I've been so dense... I've been looking at it this way $I_{\alpha+1}[f]$ = $I_\alpha[I_1[f]]$ the whole time. thanks for the answers!

Comment: Would I have to show that Ia is continuous? I'm thinking about setting a compact interval [0,c] and showing that I is continuous at x in the interior

Comment: Well, yes (to get that $I_\alpha[I_\beta[f]](x)$ is well-defined, say). With Lebesgue integration, you easily get it from the dominated convergence theorem, after rewriting $\Gamma(\alpha)I_\alpha[f](x)=\int_0^x z^{\alpha-1}f(x-z)\,dz$ and bounding $f$ uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to note that your operator $I_{\alpha}$ is the convolution on $[0,\infty)$ of $t^{-1+\alpha}/\Gamma(\alpha)$ and $f$. Applying the Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}$ gives
$$
     \mathscr{L}\{I_{\alpha}f\}=s^{\alpha}\mathscr{L}\{f\},
$$
$I_{\alpha}$ is a fractional derivative operator. In particular,
$$
       I_{\beta}I_{\alpha}f = I_{\alpha+\beta}f.
$$
This also explains why $\frac{d}{dx}I_{\alpha}f = I_{\alpha+1}f$.

Comment: thanks but I haven't learned Laplace transform yet...

Comment: can someone tell me how I should show $I_\alpha[f]$ is integrable?